# How to have CSS animation NOT consume one's entire CPU?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transforms, css-animations, vendor-prefix

I'm trying to make a loader gif using CSS animation and transforms instead. Unfortunately, the following code converts Firefox's (and sometimes Chrome's,Safari's) CPU usage on my Mac OSX  from <10% to >90%.

```
i.icon-repeat {
   display:none;
  -webkit-animation: Rotate 1s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: Rotate 1s infinite linear; //**this is the offending line**
   animation: Rotate 1s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
  from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
   to {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-keyframes Rotate {
  from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
   to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes Rotate {
  from {-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
   to {-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Note, that without the `infinite linear` rotation or the `-moz-` vendor prefix, the "loader gif"-like behavior is lost. That is, the icon doesn't continuously rotate.

Perhaps this is just a bug or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: sidenote: I know this is quite common, but (Ab)using `i` for an icon really is bad practice and you should not do that. Besides that I think you can't help it, since your code is correct and i see no other way how to do that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the opera pre fix on each of the @keyframes? (I have no experience with them, is that required?)

Comment: Why don’t you just use spin.js instead of literally reinventing the (spinning) wheel?

Comment: @Christoph `i` icon is Twitter Bootstrap syntax so perhaps unfortunately it is become quite common. I understand it thwarts the *italics* font tag but there are other CSS solutions for that...

Comment: @Cyrille I want to use my own spinner icon. Can't figure out if spin.js allows that?

Comment: @Andy thanks for catching that opera prefix mistake. That was just a copy paste error on my part. I've corrected the question now.

Comment: @timpeterson I know that this bad habit was kind of introduced by them, but this does not make it more acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my own problem. Instead of toggling the visibility of the icon, I simply added it then removed it from the DOM. The key thing I hadn't known about using CSS animations is that `display:none` vs. `display:inline` consumes CPU either way.

So instead of that, do this (combined with the CSS in my question above):

```
var icon = document.createElement("i"); //create the icon
icon.className = "icon-repeat";

document.body.appendChild(icon);  //icon append to the DOM

function removeElement(el) {    // generic function to remove element could be used elsewhere besides this example 
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}

removeElement(icon); //triggers the icon's removal from the DOM
```

Answer (score 1):

First, which version of Firefox are you using? It might be a bug but CSS3 animations are known to use a lot of CPU, for a fraction of a second. However, they are much faster than their jQuery counterpart.

It's not @-keyframes. It's @keyframes.

On a side note, I guess it's better you use something new rather than the rotating image.

Comment: i'm using Firefox 14.0.1. Can you clarify your last comment ("it's better you use..")? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for getting back really late. By different, I meant, why not use a different approach to show something is loading. Like how loading... is used on Windows 8. Get the idea?

Comment: can you include a windows8 screenshot or video link? I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug. But as with many of these vendor prefixed things, it's still very much a work in progress. For more reliable results across the board, I'd recommend using JavaScript - perhaps jQuery.

Comment: thanks. Do you have a script in mind you for clockwise rotation of an element you could include or link to in your answer?